# Does nexus 5 support chromecast 2?

Tags: chromecast, nexus-5

I bought Nexus 5 from India 3 years back.
Now I have chromecast 2 from France.
But when i tries to connect, my nexus says no compatible devices found nearby.

I tries connecting with Google Home application. Though that also i am not able to connect. It says check you T for a code but there is not code displayed on my TV (I checked my TV and I was on the right HDMI port)

Can anyone help guide me. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your chromecast is not setup properly.

Make sure you connect the chromecast through HDMI and also power it using the usb port at the same time. If you see the chromecast installation screen on your TV, then you can use Google Home to install it.

Also, the USB port on your tv is likely not to supply any power.

Comment: Yes, I connected to USB power in the wall and HDMI to TV. and I see white light blinking but i cant see installation screen on TV

Comment: The chromecast could be damaged. Try it on a different tv to verify.